# Mysql is available, but my.ini is not change in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
max_connections = 300
max_connect_errors = 1000000


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

This is my.ini contents. inserted max_connections and max_connect_errors, but not working.

I had to restart to Mysql

I show default vlaues. not changed!

[image]

Comment: Where did you take this picture?

Comment: have you tried  restart your webserver ?

Comment: Did you read the comment at the top of the file that says "*** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template" ?
I would suggest you have a look at link provided in the config file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Picture is captured in Mysql Workbench

Comment: @scaisEdge Of course. i tried that!

Comment: which OS  you are using ?

Comment: @GreensterRox I know that. but i need to change file

Comment: @scaisEdge I use Windows

Comment: which editor you use and in which way ?

Comment: @scaisEdge notepad and just save.

Comment: posted  and brief answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows  if a `.ini` file is in use this  is not updated whit  new  value when you use a normal editor.

You could override this open the .ini using and editor launche

```
 as administrator
```

(right click over the icon and run as adiministrator)

and remember that you can change the mysql env also accessing variables

```
show variables like "max_connections";

set global max_connections = 200;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html

Comment: Thank you, but not change values in workbench.
In command, success change. but not change in workbench connections.
This is command >>    max-connect-errors   1000000    max-connections        300

Comment: try ... restart webserver  ..and exit  form mysql bench mark ... (some time you need  restart the server  too)

Comment: I try restart webserver and benchmark. but same that before retart

Comment: and the database  ... you are chaning the database configuration file  ..  try restart the database server

Comment: i also restarted mysql server.

Comment: then are you sure you are editing the proper files .. ?   .. i have update answer  with  others suggestion too

Comment: It works! but if computer reboot or server restart, back to the before

Comment: this mean that you are not ediiting the proper file